# Como fazer quebra de linha dentro de um link no CakePHP

Tags: html, html5, cakephp

Sei que não é o certo mas eu tenho uma situação que eu precisei fazer uma quebra de linha dentro do *link* conforme imagem em anexo.

[image: printscreen tela de cadastro.]

Gostaria de trabalhar com o padrão *Cake* mas eu tive que fazer a quebra de linha pelo *HTML*.

Como eu faço isso pelo *Cake*?

```
<nav class="columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#DadosPrincipais">> Dados Básicos<br>
            > Telefones<br>
            > Qualificação<br>
            > Residência<br>
            > Cônjuge</a></li>
        <li><a href="#TrabalhoRendimento">> Trabalho<br>
        > Rendimentos</a></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link('> '.'Referências','#Referencia', ['style' => $matriculaButton]) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link('> '.'Comprovantes','#Comprovante', ['style' => $matriculaButton]) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionou ao colocar 'scape'=> false.
Dessa forma o link do Cake passa a aceitar o html.

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link('> Dados Básicos  <br> > Telefones <br> > Qualificação <br> > Residência <br> > Cônjuge', '#DadosPrincipais', ['escape'=>false,  'style' => $matriculaButton]); ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não trabalho com cake.

Mas acredito que você possa colocar uma classe no link. ex: class="link-block".

Se sim, você faz isso e colocar ela como block.

`.link-block {
  display: block
}`
.

No seu css.